# Intersection of two tangent of Hyperbola

Tags: geometry

If $x = 9$ is the chord of contact of the hyperbola $x^2 – y^2 = 9$, then the equation of the corresponding pair of tangents is?

I proceeded for the tangent at hyperbola using parametric equation as

$$x \sec \alpha -y \tan \alpha =3$$
$$x \sec \beta -y \tan \beta =3$$
are two tangent then intersection of these two tangent will get us x intersection but for y i am confused.

Comment: Why parameterize? You can find the points of intersection and the slopes of the tangents at those points directly from the original equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going by Samar's comments, what you are probably looking for is this:

The chord of contact of the pair of tangents drawn from $(x_1,y_1)$ is $S_1=0$ which here translates to $xx_1-yy_1 =9$. Comparing with the given chord $x=9$ we see that the pair of tangents have been drawn from $(1,0)$.

Now using that the equation to the pair of tangents from $(x_1,y_1)$ is $SS_{11} =T^2$ we get $(x^2-y^2-9)(-8) = (x-9)^2$

Comment: Thanks this answer is correct

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$y=\pm\sqrt{x^2-9}=\pm\sqrt{9^2-9}=\pm6\sqrt2$$

Can you find the equation of tangents at $(9,\pm6\sqrt2)$

Comment: The point of contact of the tangent doesn't lie on hyperbola but at some other point

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi, True. But why on earth we are interested in that? We have found the points where chord of contact intersects with the hyperbola, right?

Comment: I was browsing through the concepts on internet, $SS1=T^2$ is the equation for pair of tangent

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi, True. In that case we need to know the intersection of the tangents.

Comment: As x=9 it is chord of contact it helps us to find the coordinate(1,0). Equation of Tangent is {y=m(x-1)}, plug it into hyperbola equation. Eliminating y terms , for tangentcy$b^2=4ac$ for equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ we get two value of m after multiplying both tangent equation we get $(x^2-y^2-9)(-8) = (x-9)^2$  which is correct and answer